# VSCode asdf-vm command no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, homebrew, asdf-vm

### Specs

- VSCode 1.63.2
- Homebrew 3.3.10
- asdf 0.9.0
- MacOS Monterey

### Problem

I installed asdf via Homebrew as per doc http://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf

The `asdf` command works well in my iTerm. However, it didn't work when committing or pushing via VScode terminal and VSCode source control.

The error from VSCode terminal

```sh
Unknown command: `asdf exec npm run pre-commit`
/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.9.0/libexec/bin/asdf: line 82: /usr/local/opt/asdf/lib/commands/command-help.bash: No such file or directory
```

And this below from VSCode source control

[image]

The error I got in output.

```sh
> git push origin feature/my-branch
Unknown command: `asdf exec npm run pre-commit`
/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.9.0/libexec/bin/asdf: line 82: /usr/local/opt/asdf/lib/commands/command-help.bash: No such file or directory
```

Running `asdf exec npm run pre-commit` in my iTerm works well. There must be different configuration between zsh in iTerm vs in VSCode.

My attempt so far is to add this configuration in VSCode `settings.json`

```json
  "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
```

but still not working

My `~/.zshrc` setup for asdf

```sh
. /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

What is the possible cause here?

Answer (score 0):

Found dubious decision

I also dont have commands folder in asdf/lib

So I copied the same from asdf/libexec/lib

And it worked